# Why the same CFLAGS can be repeated twice in a makefile?

Tags: gcc, makefile, arm, stm32, cortex-m

this is the secation of makefile:

```
CFLAGS += -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv5-d16

CFLAGS  = -g -O2 -Wall
CFLAGS += -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv5-d16
```

The first line is exactly the same as the third line.

After annotating first line,the "make" does not go wrong.

But after annotating third line,the "make" goes wrong.
the error:

```
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s:77: Error: selected processor does not support `rbit r0,r0' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s:368: Error: selected processor does not support `rbit r0,r0' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s:402: Error: selected processor does not support `rbit r0,r0' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s:1276: Error: selected processor does not support `rbit r0,r0' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s:1305: Error: selected processor does not support `rbit r0,r3' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s:1371: Error: selected processor does not support `rbit r0,r0' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s:1400: Error: selected processor does not support `rbit r0,r3' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s:1544: Error: selected processor does not support `rbit r0,r0' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s:1573: Error: selected processor does not support `rbit r0,r3' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s:1643: Error: selected processor does not support `rbit r0,r0' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s:1672: Error: selected processor does not support `rbit r0,r3' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s:2989: Error: selected processor does not support `rbit r0,r0' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s:3021: Error: selected processor does not support `rbit r0,r0' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s:3060: Error: selected processor does not support `rbit r0,r0' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s:3096: Error: selected processor does not support `rbit r0,r0' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s:3342: Error: selected processor does not support `rbit r0,r0' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s:3371: Error: selected processor does not support `rbit r0,r3' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s:3443: Error: selected processor does not support `rbit r0,r0' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s:3472: Error: selected processor does not support `rbit r0,r3' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccIrbEv9.s:3783: Error: selected processor does not support `rbit r0,r0' in ARM mode
Makefile:27: recipe for target 'Src/stm32f7xx_hal_dma2d.o' failed
```

I feel confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the difference between

```
CFLAGS += ...
```

and:

```
CFLAGS = ...
```

The plus sign makes all the difference. It modifies the `CFLAGS` value by appending the flags. Without the plus sign, the value is replace and the previous value is lost.

1. The first `CFLAGS += ...` can be removed because its value is replaced by `CFLAGS = ...`.
2. `CFLAGS = ...` can be removed because the code compiles without them as well.
3. The last `CFLAGS += ...` cannot be removed as it provides compiler flags that are essential for your code.

Answer (score 3):

> CFLAGS  = -g -O2 -Wall

This row overrides the first one (note the assignment), so, if you delete the third row, you compile without these options and toolchain defaults are applied.
In this very specific case it seems that the compilator doesn't accept the sources for the default target.

Comment: Yup, [`rbit` requires ARMv6T2 or later](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289889382.htm) regardless of ARM vs. Thumb2 mode.  ARM GCC's default `-march=` is for a fairly baseline old ARM ISA version.  (`-mcpu=` sets target arch)